# Excecute an email send to client when it matches the Date/ time field

Tags: community, process-builder

How to Excecute an email send to client when it matches the Date/ time field. For example I had created a process builder stating that. Delivery date is a date/time field and dont want to make it as a date field.

When the IF(delivery date = NOW (), true, false)  then send an email to the client.

It somehow is not responding to it.

Comment: How is that ever going to fire? Date time goes down to the second. It's never going to be the same second. Have you tried instead just focusing on the date and maybe hour/minutes of the datetime leaving out the seconds part?